# Android AVD launchtime error

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Currently I am working in Windows7 which is 32 bit
I am new in Android and have recently installed Eclipse, Android SDK and ADT tools in my system
But when I try to create AVD, the error pops in the console 
Error is [2012-01-10 06:34:42 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ecllipse > Window > Android SDK Manager > System Image > Download solved my problem. The userdata.img file was missing from the system-images folder initially so the error was occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you completely downloaded the Android SDK and it's tools. If you can, initiate a re-download.